# Segmentation fault: 11 float型配列に数字を入力出来ない

Tags: c

segmentation fault 11についてです。float型の二重配列を使ってプログラムを書いていたのですが、正常に入力出来ていた変数と同様の形式の変数を作成して入力しようとするとsegmentation fault 11が発生してしまいます。
float型で要素数が１桁ずつの二重配列の場合は入力出来ます。
どうすればこの問題を解決できるか教えていただきたいです。

問題がある箇所は348行目からだと思います。一番下のコメントアウトしている部分のすぐ上です。

今まで試したことは、
float型四重配列に計算結果を入力出来なかったので、三重配列を試すも出来なかった。しかし二重配列には入力できたので、コードを書き換えていると途中から入力出来なくなった。
要素数を変数から数値での設定にすると１つの変数には入力できるが他の変数には入力出来ない。
同じ形式で要素数を減らすと入力可能だと判明。
変数名や要素数の書き方などを変更するがうまくいかず

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 256
#define class 5
#define data 10
#define MAX_ERR 1e-10 

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp_in;
    FILE *fp_out;
    char magic[64];
    char str[256];
    char readline[N] = {'\0'};
    int i,j,k,l;
    int width;
    int height;
    int max;
    int num[4];
    int train_place1[data][2]={{0,0},{0,50},{0,100},{50,50},{50,100},
                              {100,100},{100,150},{150,150},{150,200},{200,200}};
    int train_place2[data][2]={{150,320},{180,300},{180,330},{200,270},
                              {200,300},{200,330},{230,270},{230,310},{250,250},{250,290}};
    int train_place3[data][2]={{300,260},{300,280},{320,240},{320,260},
                              {320,280},{320,300},{350,260},{350,280},{350,300},{370,300}};
    int train_place4[data][2]={{250,335},{260,320},{270,300},{280,280},
                              {285,270},{290,260},{295,240},{305,225},{310,210},{320,180}};
    int train_place5[data][2]={{280,180},{280,190},{290,170},{290,180},
                              {290,190},{300,150},{300,170},{300,190},{320,130},{320,150}};
    int train_date1[data][3]={0};
    int train_date2[data][3]={0};
    int train_date3[data][3]={0};
    int train_date4[data][3]={0};
    int train_date5[data][3]={0};
    float sum[class][3]={0};
    float sum2[3][3]={0};
    float mean_vector[class][3];
    float covariance[class][3][3];
    float a;
    float mat[3][3];
    float inv[3][3];
    float co_inv[class][3][3];
    float sweep[3][6];
    fp_in = fopen("irabu.ppm", "r");

    //magic
    fgets(magic, N, fp_in);
    //width, height
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        fscanf(fp_in, "%d", &num[i]);
    }
    width = num[0];
    height = num[1];
    int image_in[height][width*3];
    int image_out[height][width][3];
    //max
    fscanf(fp_in, "%d", &max);
    //image
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < width*3; j++){
            fscanf(fp_in, "%d", &image_in[i][j]);
        }
    }
fclose(fp_in);

    for(i=0;i<data;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            train_date1[i][j] = image_in[train_place1[i][1]][train_place1[i][0]*3+j];
        }
    }
       for(i=0;i<data;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            train_date2[i][j] = image_in[train_place2[i][1]][train_place2[i][0]*3+j];
        }
    }
       for(i=0;i<data;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            train_date3[i][j] = image_in[train_place3[i][1]][train_place3[i][0]*3+j];
        }
    }
       for(i=0;i<data;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            train_date4[i][j] = image_in[train_place4[i][1]][train_place4[i][0]*3+j];
        }
    }
       for(i=0;i<data;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            train_date5[i][j] = image_in[train_place5[i][1]][train_place5[i][0]*3+j];
        }
    }

        for(j=0;j<data;j++){//クラス1
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum[0][k] += train_date1[j][k];
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<data;j++){//クラス2
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum[1][k] += train_date2[j][k];
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<data;j++){//クラス3
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum[2][k] += train_date3[j][k];
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<data;j++){//クラス４
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum[3][k] += train_date4[j][k];
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<data;j++){//クラス5
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum[4][k] += train_date5[j][k];
            }
        }

    for(i=0;i<class;i++){//平均ベクトル
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            mean_vector[i][j] = sum[i][j]/data;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<data;i++){//分散共分散 クラス１
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum2[j][k] += (train_date1[i][j]-mean_vector[0][j])*(train_date1[i][k]-mean_vector[0][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            covariance[0][i][j] = sum2[i][j]/data;
            sum2[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<data;i++){//分散共分散 クラス2
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum2[j][k] += (train_date2[i][j]-mean_vector[1][j])*(train_date2[i][k]-mean_vector[1][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            covariance[1][i][j] = sum2[i][j]/data;
            sum2[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<data;i++){//分散共分散 クラス3
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum2[j][k] += (train_date3[i][j]-mean_vector[2][j])*(train_date3[i][k]-mean_vector[2][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            covariance[2][i][j] = sum2[i][j]/data;
            sum2[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<data;i++){//分散共分散 クラス4
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum2[j][k] += (train_date4[i][j]-mean_vector[3][j])*(train_date4[i][k]-mean_vector[3][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            covariance[3][i][j] = sum2[i][j]/data;
            sum2[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<data;i++){//分散共分散 クラス5
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                sum2[j][k] += (train_date5[i][j]-mean_vector[4][j])*(train_date5[i][k]-mean_vector[4][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            covariance[4][i][j] = sum2[i][j]/data;
            sum2[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    float det[5]={0};//行列式
  for(i=0;i<class;i++){
      for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        det[i] = det[i] + covariance[i][0][j] * ( covariance[i][1][(j+1)%3] * covariance[i][2][(j+2)%3] - covariance[i][1][(j+2)%3] * covariance[i][2][(j+1)%3] );
      }
  }

for(l=0;l<class;l++){

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        mat[i][j]=covariance[0][i][j];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            /* sweepの左側に逆行列を求める行列をセット */
            sweep[i][j] = mat[i][j];

            /* sweepの右側に単位行列をセット */
            sweep[i][3 + j] = (i == j) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }


    /* 全ての列の対角成分に対する繰り返し */
    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

        /* sweep[k][k]に掛けると1になる値を求める */
        a = 1 / sweep[k][k];

        /* 操作（２）：k行目をa倍する */
        for (j = 0; j < 3 * 2; j++) {
            /* これによりsweep[k][k]が1になる */
            sweep[k][j] *= a;
        }

        /* 操作（３）によりk行目以外の行のk列目を0にする */
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (i == k) {
                /* k行目はそのまま */
                continue;
            }

            /* k行目に掛ける値を求める */
            a = -sweep[i][k];

            for (j = 0; j < 3 * 2; j++) {
                /* i行目にk行目をa倍した行を足す */
                /* これによりsweep[i][k]が0になる */
                sweep[i][j] += sweep[k][j] * a; 
            }
        }
    }

    /* sweepの右半分がmatの逆行列 */
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            inv[i][j] = sweep[i][3 + j];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      for(j=0;j<3;j++){
           co_inv[l][i][j]=inv[i][j];
        }
    }  
}

float under[class]={0.0};
double PI2=M_PI*2;
double ep1 = 3*width*height/2;
double ep2 = width*height/2;
for(i=0;i<class;i++){
    under[i]= pow(PI2,ep1) * pow(det[i],ep2);
}

int image[height][width][3];

for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        for(k=0;k<3;k++){
            image[i][j][k]=image_in[i][j+k];
        }
    }
}

float rgb[3];
float rgb_mean[class][3];

for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        for(k=0;k<3;k++){
            rgb[k]+=image[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    rgb[i]=rgb[i]/(height*width);
}

for(i=0;i<class;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        rgb_mean[i][j]=rgb[j]-mean_vector[i][j];
    }
}

float cal1[class][3]={0.0};
for(i=0;i<class;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        cal1[i][j]=rgb_mean[i][0]*co_inv[i][0][j]+rgb_mean[i][1]*co_inv[i][1][j]
                 +rgb_mean[i][2]*co_inv[i][2][j];
    }
}

float cal2[class]={0.0};
for(i=0;i<class;i++){
    cal2[i]=cal1[i][0]*rgb_mean[i][0]+cal1[i][1]*rgb_mean[i][1]
           +cal1[i][2]*rgb_mean[i][2];
}


float cal3[height][width][3];
for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        for(k=0;k<3;k++){   
            cal3[i][j][k]=image[i][j][k]-rgb[k];
        }
    }
}

float cal_1r[height][width];
float cal_1g[height][width];
float cal_1b[height][width];
for(i=0;i<height;i++){//クラス１
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        cal_1r[i][j]=(cal3[i][j][0]*co_inv[0][0][0])+(cal3[i][j][1]*co_inv[0][1][0])
                        +(cal3[i][j][2]*co_inv[0][2][0]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        cal_1g[i][j]=(cal3[i][j][0]*co_inv[0][0][1])+(cal3[i][j][1]*co_inv[0][1][1])
                    +(cal3[i][j][2]*co_inv[0][2][1]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        cal_1b[i][j]=(cal3[i][j][0]*co_inv[0][0][2])+(cal3[i][j][1]*co_inv[0][1][2])
                    +(cal3[i][j][2]*co_inv[0][2][2]);          
    }
}

printf("\nok\n");
float cal_2r[height][width];
float cal_2g[350][450]={0.0};
//float cal_2b[height][width];

for(i=0;i<height;i++){//クラス2
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        cal_2r[i][j]=(cal3[i][j][0]*co_inv[1][0][0])+(cal3[i][j][1]*co_inv[1][1][0])
                        +(cal3[i][j][2]*co_inv[1][2][0]);
    }
}

/*
for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        cal_2g[i][j]=(cal3[i][j][0]*co_inv[1][0][1])+(cal3[i][j][1]*co_inv[1][1][1])
                    +(cal3[i][j][2]*co_inv[1][2][1]);
    }
}
*/


/*


float cal_3r[height][width];
float cal_3g[height][width];
float cal_3b[height][width];

float cal_4r[height][width];
float cal_4g[height][width];
float cal_4b[height][width];

float cal_5r[height][width];
float cal_5g[height][width];
float cal_5b[height][width];
for(i=0;i<height;i++){//クラス2
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        cal_2r[i][j]=(cal3[i][j][0]*co_inv[1][0][0])+(cal3[i][j][1]*co_inv[1][1][0])
                        +(cal3[i][j][2]*co_inv[1][2][0]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<350;i++){
    for(j=0;j<450;j++){
        cal_3g[i][j]=(cal3[i][j][0]*co_inv[0][0][1])+(cal3[i][j][1]*co_inv[0][1][1])
                    +(cal3[i][j][2]*co_inv[0][2][1]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<350;i++){
    for(j=0;j<450;j++){
        cal_3b[i][j]=(cal3[i][j][0]*co_inv[0][0][2])+(cal3[i][j][1]*co_inv[0][1][2])
                    +(cal3[i][j][2]*co_inv[0][2][2]);          
    }
}
*/

/*

float cal5[class][height][width];
for(i=0;i<class;i++){
    for(j=0;j<height;j++){
        for(k=0;k<width;k++){
            cal5[i][j][k]=cal4[i][j][k][0]*cal3[j][k][0]+cal4[i][j][k][1]*cal3[j][k][1]
                         +cal4[i][j][k][2]*cal3[j][k][2];
        }
    }
}

float Lx[class][height][width];
for(i=0;i<class;i++){
    for(j=0;j<height;j++){
        for(k=0;k<width;k++){
            Lx[i][j][k] = exp((-width*height*0.5*cal2[i]-0.5*cal5[i][j][k])/under[i]);
        }
    }
}

for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
        if(Lx[0][i][j]>Lx[1][i][j] && Lx[0][i][j]>Lx[2][i][j] &&
           Lx[0][i][j]>Lx[3][i][j] && Lx[0][i][j]>Lx[3][i][j]){
               image_out[i][j][0]=mean_vector[0][0];
               image_out[i][j][1]=mean_vector[0][1];
               image_out[i][j][2]=mean_vector[0][2];
        }
        else if(Lx[1][i][j]>Lx[0][i][j] && Lx[1][i][j]>Lx[2][i][j] &&
                Lx[1][i][j]>Lx[3][i][j] && Lx[1][i][j]>Lx[4][i][j]){
               image_out[i][j][0]=mean_vector[1][0];
               image_out[i][j][1]=mean_vector[1][1];
               image_out[i][j][2]=mean_vector[1][2];
        } 
        else if(Lx[2][i][j]>Lx[0][i][j] && Lx[2][i][j]>Lx[1][i][j] &&
                Lx[2][i][j]>Lx[3][i][j] && Lx[2][i][j]>Lx[4][i][j]){
               image_out[i][j][0]=mean_vector[2][0];
               image_out[i][j][1]=mean_vector[2][1];
               image_out[i][j][2]=mean_vector[2][2];
        }
        else if(Lx[3][i][j]>Lx[0][i][j] && Lx[3][i][j]>Lx[1][i][j] &&
                Lx[3][i][j]>Lx[2][i][j] && Lx[3][i][j]>Lx[4][i][j]){
               image_out[i][j][0]=mean_vector[3][0];
               image_out[i][j][1]=mean_vector[3][1];
               image_out[i][j][2]=mean_vector[3][2]; 
        } 
        else if(Lx[4][i][j]>Lx[0][i][j] && Lx[4][i][j]>Lx[1][i][j] &&
                Lx[4][i][j]>Lx[2][i][j] && Lx[4][i][j]>Lx[3][i][j]){
               image_out[i][j][0]=mean_vector[4][0];
               image_out[i][j][1]=mean_vector[4][1];
               image_out[i][j][2]=mean_vector[4][2]; 
        }else{
            image_out[i][j][0]= image[i][j][0];
            image_out[i][j][1]= image[i][j][1];
            image_out[i][j][2]= image[i][j][2];
        }
    }
}*/

/*
    fp_out = fopen("imori.ppm", "w");

    fprintf(fp_out, "%s", magic);
    fprintf(fp_out, "%d ", width);
    fprintf(fp_out, "%d\n", height);
    fprintf(fp_out, "%d\n", max);

    for(i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
            fprintf(fp_out, "%d ", image_out[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
        fprintf(fp_out, "\n");
    }*/
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 現在質問者さん本人と思われる方から編集提案がされていますが、本来質問者自身であれば質問は自由に編集できます。もしアカウン‌​‌​トが2つに分かれてしまった場合は、[ア‌​カウ‌​ントのマージ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を行ってください。

Comment: gccがサポートしている可変長配列(VLA)らしいですが、一つの関数の中で何度も定義・使用しているのでスタックを使い切ってしまったとかでは？ [ARR32-C. 可変長配列のサイズ引数は適切な範囲内にあることを保証する](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-arr32-c.html) 相互に関係しないならば処理を別関数に分割するとか、常に同時に巨大なメモリが必要ならヒープから確保するとかすれば良いのでは？

Comment: 他にはこんな記事 [プログラムのスタックサイズを変更する](http://www.hiraku.ro/tdiary/?date=20081216) を参考にコンパイル・リンク時に試しにスタックサイズを巨大な値に変更してみては？

Comment: あと再現・調査などのためには`irabu.ppm`というファイルの提示が必要でしょう。ダミーデータで良いので問題が再現できる内容のものを提示するか、あるいはそれが無くても問題を再現出来るように質問のソースコードを変えてみてください。